# Android facebook login with email

Tags: java, android, facebook, http

I am trying to make an application which logs into facebook by asking for the email and the password of the user, without taking him to the WebView pop-up. Is there any way to do this? I have been trying to do some HTTP manipulation but i couldn't succeed!
Thank you!

Comment: BTW, asking for the email and password directly is against the Facebook Platform Policies (I.2) - https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the latest Facebook SDK for android, v3.6.0, https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk, the default behavior is:

- If the user doesn't have the Facebook app installed, then the user will see the web view popup and has to type username and password manually.
- If the user has the Facebook app installed, but hasn't approved the permissions, then your app will switch to Facebook app where the user can approve the permissions and come back to your app.
- If the user has the Facebook app installed and already approved the permissions, and the user will see a native android dialog.

At any time, if you change permission requirements, then since the user needs to approve the additional permissions, in that case your app will also switch to the Facebook app.

If you don't want to provide native support, you have to handle all of these and has to frequently update your code, because Facebook updates its SDK and deprecates old methods quite often. The best practice is simply sticking to the Facebook SDK, unless you have any other requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Android Dont provide native support of facebook and twitter integration so i think you must pop up atleast one time for login facebook then you save user email to your local db and then use it :)